# Getting different outputs for python timezone calculation function locally and on server

Tags: python, pytz

I use the following function to calculate reporting date ranges for different timezones.  For some reason I am getting different outputs when I run this locally vs. on a server.  I can't figure out what part of the function would make this happen?

```
import calendar
import pytz

from datetime import datetime, time

def get_international_dates(timezone):
    tz = pytz.timezone(timezone)
    today = datetime.now(tz).date()
    midnight = tz.localize(datetime.combine(today, time(0, 0)), is_dst=True)
    last_full_day_midnight = int(midnight.astimezone(pytz.utc).strftime("%s"))
    week_end = last_full_day_midnight - 3600
    week_start = last_full_day_midnight - (3600 * 24 * 7)
    prev_week_end = week_end - (3600 * 24 * 7)
    prev_week_start = week_start - (3600 * 24 * 7)
    return {'start': week_start, 'end': week_end, 'prev_start': prev_week_start, 'prev_end': prev_week_end}
```

When I call the function with a timezone locally (I'm EST) `get_international_dates('Europe/Berlin')`

I get the following output:

```
{'end': 1468548000,
 'prev_end': 1467943200,
 'prev_start': 1467342000,
 'start': 1467946800}
```

When this script runs on the server, I see the following output in the logs for the same timezone:

```
{'end': 1468530000,
 'prev_end': 1467925200,
 'prev_start': 1467324000,
 'start': 1467928800}
```

Why and I getting different timestamps and how can I remedy this?

Comment: I think you should use `strftime("%S")`. "%s" results in ValueError-Exception

Comment: @Humbalan  It runs fine for me with `"%s"`  I tried `"%S"` and got very, very incorrect results

Comment: That's strange. If I copy your code I get this Exception and I didn't find %s in any documentation of strftime().

Comment: the differences of your results are always 5 hours. And this ist the add of the EST timezone to UTC (now returns "EST 2016-07-15 10:39:18.041000-05:00"). Maybe your server runs with UTC.

Comment: @Humbalan that would make sense, but idk where in the function that would make a difference